# Tuning Old Music Tapes

Tags: tuning

Can old out of tune original music tapes be tuned up to A440? Is there a device that could do it?  Of course the music would be copied to a file and then the file tuned to A440. I would like to put them into a DAW and overdub.
Appreciate any input. Thanks

Comment: So you're really asking if there is a way to convert tapes to digital audio files?

Answer (score 1):

Most DAWs have speed and pitch controls or plug-ins that you can use for this. It will most likely be a process of trial and error to determine exactly how much you want to shift any given recording. I would personally tune up an instrument or use a keyboard alongside the DAW and try to compare the tuning while playing along. You could also try watching an automatic chromatic tuner to see if each note is consistently sharp or flat.

Comment: Thanks Todd. Do any of those pitch controls/plug ins have an A440 meter setting? (showing when the recording hits the right key, like tuning a Guitar string up)  I have Sound Forge but don't know it well, use a 24 track Tascam more. All my tapes are now digital files. Thanks

Comment: I'm not aware of a plug-in or software package that can tell what tuning was used on a recording, which is why I said you'll probably have to do it by ear.

Comment: Hm. Might be an opp to create such a tuner. Good to find a key fast on a recording and to play along so could be popular like a guitar tuner and . good for all instruments.